# Why checkbox event status returns string "on" instead of true/false?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a custom checkbox as child component which is being added in a parent component. I pass the **`ngModel`**, **`name`** etc. correctly and try to update the **`model`** with the status **`true/false`** based on checkbox status using **`EventEmitter`**.

Unfortunately the status I get is **`"on"`** as a **`string`** instead of **`boolean`**

Via Chrome console, I can track the status and the **`event`**. It works correct and puts out the expected result. Just the `model` and two way binding gets a string value and in my case it's **`"on"`**, and it keeps this string even if I uncheck the checkbox. in other words there is even no `"off"`

**child.component.html:**

```
<input type="checkbox"
        name="{{passCheckBoxName}}" 
        #ngForm="ngModel"
        [ngModel]="model" 
        (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
        required>
```

**child.component.ts**:

```
@Input() model: boolean;
@Output() modelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

onChange(event) {
    console.log('this.model: ' + ${this.model});
    this.model = event;
    // event.checked doesn't work for me. output then is undefined
    // this.model = event.checked;
    console.log(event);
    this.modelChange.emit( event ); 
    // event.checked doesn't work for me. output then is undefined
    // this.modelChange.emit( event.checked ); 
}
```

**parent.component.html**:

```
<child-checkbox [parentFormGroup]="form"
                [name]="'nameOfCheckbox'"
                [ngModel]="name"" 
                ngDefaultControl>
</child-checkbox>
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using e.g. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com). I've created a simpler version of this that works as expected (with `true` and `false`).

Comment: Sorry, If I understand you, you have created a demo for that on Stackbliz which works as it should be. Returns `true/false`. I just can see a sample for an angular app start/basic.

Comment: No - I'm suggesting *you* create a demo of your issue on Stackblitz as I am unable to reproduce your problem myself.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Never have build a sample on Sblitz.

Comment: It doesn't have to be Stackblitz - You can create a Github repo or something else. We just need something that's complete and shows the problem.

Comment: Ok, here is the [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7lx7wc?file=app%2Fcheckbox%2Fcheckbox.component.ts). Thee you can also find a part of code which is commented out and it's the one which works as expected, but it's not via child component. It's embedded directly in the main component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174362/discussion-between-k-vincent-and-kirk-larkin).

Answer (score 1):

I have done some code for you:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-odkm2n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.html
the model value is boolean here
1. Why you create the child component only with checkbox?
2. Why you use Input() with "model" when you event don't take it into the child component? (also for the Output())

Comment: I don't see what you're talking about at all. Following the link, I get an empty app from your StackBlitz link. Sorry.

Comment: I see now what you mean. But the  issue is about a checkbox and event with boolean status true/false which should be passed to the model.

Comment: To your question regarding creating the separated component for just one `checkbox`, I would like to be flexible adding multiple checkboxes in the parent component and make the `label`, `name`, `placeholder`etc. configurable as much as possible. And therefore having a custom form. I do also have custom input and buttons.

Comment: Could you tell me, are you emmiting true/false value when checbox checked?

Comment: you check the checkbox, value of the checkbox set into variable model and then we can emmit it to parent component with this.modelChange.emit(model)

Comment: Yes, I do. Please see the function `onChange()`. I did `this.modelChange.emit( event ) and `this.modelChange.emit( this.model )`. none of them worked as expected.

Comment: you should just delete onChange() argument because the check box state is in variable model yet

Comment: True. I did. Issue persists.

Comment: Yes, It's weird. [Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7lx7wc?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html&view=editor). Can you access the code?

Comment: Sure. I can suggest you do not use form for output, but use something like that https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-odkm2n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I did some modification.. also based on your hint. Seems to work, except then the form validation. The button should be disabled when false (checkbox is not checked) and enabled when form is valid (checkbox checked).You can see what I mean in the pervious StackBlitz [link I poasted](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7lx7wc?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html&view=editor). It not reacting regading `form.valid` `form.invalid` causs I use now: `[ngModule]="value"` instead of `[ngModule]="name"`.

Comment: Ok, why not you disable button using the model variable

Comment: <button [disabled]=!model>

Comment: No, didn't help. Let us continue on [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174362/discussion-between-k-vincent-and-kirk-larkin)